# Delete a part of array elements in js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Array and want to delete `X` element and All elements after `'X'` element in array and return previous elements

This is my array : `['A' , 'B' , 'C' , 'D' , 'X' , 'Z' , 'A' , 'B' , 'F']`

And the new array I want is this : `['A' , 'B' , 'C' , 'D']`

How can I did this?

Comment: Do you want to modify the array, or just return a new array with the previous elements?

Comment: Just modify the array

Comment: Use `array.splice()` starting from the index of `X`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to get the index of the target and [`Array.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get the items from index 0 to the index of the target:

```js
const arr = ['A' , 'B' , 'C' , 'D' , 'X' , 'Z' , 'A' , 'B' , 'F']
const target = 'X'

const res = arr.slice(0, arr.indexOf(target))

console.log(res)
```

If you want to modify the original, use [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) instead:

```js
const arr = ['A' , 'B' , 'C' , 'D' , 'X' , 'Z' , 'A' , 'B' , 'F']
const target = 'X'

arr.splice(arr.indexOf(target))

console.log(arr)
```